# How do I create transformed nested JSON elements with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file with nested elements that I'm trying to manipulate into an unnested JSON file. How do I do this?

Using js, I have tried to isolate the percentages, which I was able to do. I'm not sure how to rename the percentage field. I've seen instances where it seems like value.gender or value.grade should work, but I'm also not sure how to combine it.

```js
jq '.data[] | .id as $id | (.demographics[] | .percentage as $percentage | .gender as $gender | .grade as $grade | {"id":$id, "percentage":$percentage})' test2.json
```

From here, I want to be able to rename the percentage field to the gender and grades values. I then want to group by id.

Here is the original JSON file (test2.json):

```
{
   "data": [{
         "id": "abc",
         "students": "elementary",
         "demographics": [{
               "grade": "K-2",
               "percentage": "0.1",
               "gender": "unspecified"
            },
            {
               "grade": "K-2",
               "gender": "male",
               "percentage": "0.5"
            },
            {
               "gender": "female",
               "percentage": "0.4",
               "grade": "K-2"
            },
            {
               "grade": "3-6",
               "percentage": "0.3",
               "gender": "male"
            },
            {
               "percentage": "0.2",
               "gender": "unspecified",
               "grade": "3-6"
            },
            {
               "grade": "3-6",
               "gender": "female",
               "percentage": "0.5"
            }
         ],

         "neighborhood_name": [{
               "percentage": "0.5",
               "neighborhood": "atwood"
            },
            {
               "region": "bluff",
               "percentage": "0.5"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": "def",
         "students": "midhigh",
         "demographics": [{
               "grade": "7-9",
               "percentage": "0.2",
               "gender": "unspecified"
            },
            {
               "grade": "7-9",
               "gender": "male",
               "percentage": "0.2"
            },
            {
               "gender": "female",
               "percentage": "0.6",
               "grade": "7-9"
            },
            {
               "grade": "10-12",
               "percentage": "0.1",
               "gender": "male"
            },
            {
               "percentage": "0.1",
               "gender": "unspecified",
               "grade": "10-12"
            },
            {
               "grade": "10-12",
               "gender": "female",
               "percentage": "0.8"
            }
         ],

         "neighborhood_name": [{
               "percentage": "0.2",
               "neighborhood": "atwood"
            },
            {
               "region": "bluff",
               "percentage": "0.8"
            }
         ]

      }
   ]
}
```

Here is what I expect:

```
{
         "id": "abc",
         "students": "elementary",
         "demo_K-2_unspecified": "0.1",
         "demo_K-2_male": "0.5",
         "demo_K-2_female": "0.4",
         "demo_3-6_male": "0.3",
         "demo_3-6_unspecified": "0.6",
         "demo_3-6_female": "0.5",
            },
      {
         "id": "def",
         "students": "midhigh",
         "demo_7-9_unspecified": "0.2",
         "demo_7-9_male": "0.2",
         "demo_7-9_female": "0.6",
         "demo_10-12_male": "0.1",
         "demo_10-12_unspecified": "0.1",
         "demo_10-12_female": "0.8",

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample data, the following filter produces the desired output:

```
.data[]
| {id, students} as $ix
| .demographics
| map( {"demo_\(.grade)_\(.gender)": .percentage} )
| $ix + add
```

The main idea here is to use `map` to create a list of the key-value pairs, so that the composite object can then easily be created using `add`.

### As a one-liner

```
jq '.data[] | {id,students} + (.demographics | map( {"demo_\(.grade)_\(.gender)": .percentage} ) | add)' test2.json
```

Comment: that is a good example. the $ix returns two dictionaries, the add returns two dictionaries.  + adds the first ix to the first map and the second ix to the second map? hard to wrap my head around that. I isolated the $ix output and the map add output to see the data. what is interesting to me is the arrays from the map 'leak' past the ix + part.  makes sense. the one liner helps. so the + sign between lists of dictionaries is like matrix merging.